# Операции сравнения

Tags: style-guide, code-style, css

Читаю чужой javaScript и вижу такое:

```
if(0==foo)
if(false !== bar)
if(2<=baz)
```

Есть ли причины использовать такую очередность? Привычнее видеть 
другое:

```
if(foo==0)
if(bar !== false)
if(baz >= 2)
```

Comment: От перестановки слагаемых сумма не меняется! Причина лишь в том что вам привычен 2 вариант, а автору кода 1!

Comment: Привычнее, потому что так пишет большинство кодеров. Я тоже за такой вариант.

Comment: Условия Йодa=)

Comment: @Khvorostin, на форуме принято использовать дефис в качестве разделителя в метках, а не нижнее подчеркивание.

Comment: @Angry Bird, исправляюсь. Все-таки, мне кажется что для идеи стиля лучше подходит style-guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тоже встречал такой стиль. Думаю установка константы слева позволяет избежать ошибочного использования присвоения вместо сравнения. Ещё один вариант для наглядности в случае проверки интервала,
например математическое 2 < x < 4 трансформируется в C 2 < x && x < 4.

Comment: С первым согласен. Более того, видел реальные соглашения, требующие при сравнении на равенство с константой, ставить константу слева. ИМХО, жертвовать читабельностью кода ради мифического профита от такой защиты неразумно.

Со вторым несогласен. `2 < x < 4` НЕ трансформируется в `2 < x && x < 4`. Результат первой операции отношения (0 или 1) сравнивается затем с четверкой. Рассмотрим пример.

    int s;
    s = 0; if (2 < s < 4) printf("Yiihaaa!\n");
    s = 3; if (2 < s < 4) printf("Yiihaaa!\n");
    s = 5; if (2 < s < 4) printf("Yiihaaa!\n");

Все три условия истинны.

Comment: имелось ввиду, что математическая запись трансформируется программистом в код, а не код трансформируется компилятором в что-то ещё

Comment: @northerner, читайте внимательней, 2 < x < 4 здесь математическое условие не относящееся к ЯП, а 
2 < x && x < 4 выражение в Си

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто очень. Стилю Йоды сишкопроблемы причиной являются.

```
#define c (2 * 2);  // в сях не было констант и приходилось так
int a = 2;
int b = a * a + 1;
if ( b == c ) doSometing();
if ( b = c ) doElsething(); // лёгкая опечатка пропускается транслятором
                            // и серьезно ломает логику
```

Но Йода спешит на помощь тут:

```
if ( с == b ) doSometing();
if ( c = b ) doElsething(); // в случае опечатки транслятор остановится и укажет ошибку
```

Comment: Всегда считал, что нужно отрывать руки тем, сейчас пишет кто так. Ну вот зачем специально жертвовать четкостью при написании условий и способствовать тому, чтобы у людей, которые читают код, цеплялся за это глаз? "Защищенность" и польза от этого, в общем-то, надуманная, тем более, что ворнинги компилятора и `lint` еще никто не отменял.

Comment: комменты к коду тоже можно общем стиле изложения написать

Comment: Добавлю к @karmadro4, данный стиль используется в коде на `С` для того, чтобы избежать опечатки, присваивания вместо сравнения переменной с константой. `if (var = 0)` катит, `if (0 = var)` не катит.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще, вопрос почти не имеет смысла. Это то же самое, что спрашивать:

```
0 + 1
```

Неужели не удобнее так:

```
1+0
```

Comment: @Dexter, как выясняется, разница все-таки есть.

Answer (score 0):

Например, в Java этот способ сравнения

```
("string".equals(var))
```

рекомендуют применять чаше этого, типа он быстрее

```
(var.equals("string"))
```

Есть такие вещи как как...

> В Java поддерживается специальная
> сокращенная схема выполнения
> операторов AND и OR; она позволяет
> повысить эффективность работы
> генерируемого кода. Если первый из
> двух операндов оператора AND равен
> false, результат будет равен false,
> независимо от значения второго
> операнда.

Comment: Второе никак не связано с вопросом.

Comment: возможно, но это объясняет смысл иногда задуматься о порядке сравнения элементов.